# Handling '\&' from java to SP ( except set define/scan off)

Tags: java, sql, oracle

The way to handle '**&**' is to use set define off or set scan off but problem is i am told not use set scan off in SP since we will be running this SP regularly from java code .is there any alternative way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only when using sqlplus or a similar tool that translates user input would you need to escape the `&` character.

In a java application calling a stored procedure, the `&` would be treated as a regular character and wouldn't need escaping.